# Adding image in a cell of jqxgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid

i have used Jqxgrid for a project which successfully loads data from a json string passed to it as a data source. i want to display images/icons in a column cell again each particular entry/row. Following code initializes the grid:

```
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: 850,
            source: dataAdapter,                
            pageable: true,
            autoheight: true,
            sortable: true,
            altrows: true,
            enabletooltips: true,
            editable: true,
            theme: 'energyblue',
            selectionmode: 'multiplecellsadvanced',
            columns: [
           align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: 200 },

              { text: 'SendMail', columngroup: 'Mail Details', datafield: 'ID', width: 50 },
              { text: 'Content Type', columngroup: 'Mail Details', datafield: 'LinkFilename', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right', width: 200 },
              { text: 'Sender', columngroup: 'Mail Details', datafield: 'Sender', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: 200 },
              { text: 'Date', datafield: 'Created', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer, width: 250 },

            ],
            columngroups: [
                { text: 'Mail Details', align: 'center', name: 'Mail Details' }
            ]
        });
```

Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image Column in JqxGrid. [Tutorial](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-grid-with-image-column/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but its not an image column ( thats only the column name), it's basically'cellsrenderer' property in column definition that does the trick.

Comment: Yeah, my fault.. But that isn't what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I resolved it using the same method a few days back, just couldn't update the post. Thanks anyways. :)